# How do I copy files onto the hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, internet-connection

I have never used Linux before, but I am temporarily until I can afford Win 7. I want to pre-install some programs onto the HDD so that I will already have them when I get Win 7. I have the programs on an external HD, I just don't know where to copy them to.

Just as a side note, I am also having issue connecting to the internet. It recognizes the wired connection, and it is connected to it, but yet, no internet. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ubuntu (or any linux) can not install programs for windows

Comment: @Web-E linux/ubuntu can, but only to run in linux (see WINE, windows emulator)

Answer (score 0):

You can't Pre-Install Programs in Windows as it's Registry can't be modified properly to accommodate the new Programs. Especially on a Windows Install that doesn't yet exist. Portable Programs that don't need to be installed can be moved over though.

As for copying files to Windows, First you need to have an actual Windows Partition(If you simply wiped Windows from your Harddrive when you installed Ubuntu this is not possible). Then open Nautilus(The File Manager, Orange Folder in Dash) on the left-hand side there should be a list of other Partitions on you Computer, simply click on the Windows one and it should mount and open the folder. If it doesn't appear there, open Disk Utility and make sure that Ubuntu detects it, if not please inform me using the comments.

Comment: I currently only have a copy of Windows xp, not 7. I originally tried installing that, but inorder to do so, I needed to install a hard drive driver for SATA hard drives because XP is so old. In order to install the driver, I need a floppy drive. Do you think it is possible to start the install for XP on a separate partition, then come onto Ubuntu, copy the driver over to the XP partition, then continue on my merry way with the XP install? It sounds long and complicated, but right now, it is my only option for Windows, and gaming, which is the main purpose of this build.

Comment: @Zared Am I understanding correctly that the Windows XP installer can't detect your HDD because of the missing driver and so the needed driver needs to be provided during Installation? If so this gets complicated. Does the XP Installer detect USB drives? If so it'd be better to put the driver on that to then provide the driver for the installer. If that doesn't work you'll need to obtain a Windows XP with SP3 Install Disk for your XP version(Home,Pro, etc...). It won't be pirating since you have the Licence key and just need the Install Disk with the latest ServicePack included.